# how to coerce meteor iron:router params to an integer?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I often have code that forces params to be an integer, i was wondering if there's a better way with IR to handle this frequent case:

```
@route 'units',
  path: "/units/:book?"
  name: 'units'
  waitOn: ->
    book = parseInt(@params.book)
    PubSubMan.subscribe "Tiles", {book: book}
```

This is a pain as the `parseInt(@params.book)` has to be done in find queries that use the params too, and i also need to guard against non-numbers, etc etc.

Seems that sort of type casting could be a router level option but could't find anything [in the docs](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
this.route('units', {
  path: /^\/units\/(\d+)/
});
```

Make sure to try with/without last slash in the path and update regular expression to your needs.

You can access parameter with:

```
this.params[0]
```

Comment: thanks Roman. that will make sure to only catch matching URLs with numbers in, but the params are still returned as strings.  eg   ` path: /^\/slides\/(\w+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/ `  comes out as  ["A", "1", "1", hash: null, query: Object]

Comment: @dcsan since you know that parameter with index 1 is a number, you can easily convert it to the number by multiplying by 1. Something like: var number = this.params[1] * 1;

Comment: is that better than `parseInt` ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Roman's suggestion to work, as a regular expression object does not seem to be allowed as a path.  I get the error described here:
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/887

`Exception in template helper: Error: Cannot currently resolve a regular expression path`

Instead, I found this to be useful: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#custom-match-parameters

In short, I would try the following:

```
this.route('units', {
    path: '/units/:book(\\d+)?'
});
```

And then you can use `this.params.book` as you normally would.